# Delayed stream invalidation in a loop

Tags: c++, stream

A program reads `int` values via `cin` and displays their count. `cin` is used as the `while` loop test.

Strangely, even with a non-integral input the loop increments the count i.e. the loop executes at least once even after stream invalidation before exiting.

In other words, for input

```
2.53
```

ouput is

```
1
```

As per *C++ Primer,5e by Lippman, Lajoie, Moo*

> > When we use an istream as a condition, the effect is to test the state of the
> >     stream. If the stream is valid—that is, if the stream hasn’t encountered an error—then
> >     the test succeeds. An istream becomes invalid when we hit end-of-file or encounter
> >     an **invalid input**, such as reading a value that is not an integer. An istream that is in
> >     an invalid state will cause the condition to yield false.

Since the stream is invalidated upon trying to read a double, why does the loop execute anyways and then exit only in the next  iteration?

**Code**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
int main()
{

    int a;
    int count = 0;
    while (cin >> a)
        cout << ++count << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Beginner so any help is thoroughly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because it successfully reads the `2` part of the `2.53` into `a`. It then loops back round again, tries to do something with the `.` and then drops out of the loop.

You can see this in action if you also log what was read, i.e.:

```
while (cin >> a)
{
    cout << a << " " << ++count << endl;
}
```